# is there a way to remove elements on a list through indexes entered on a text box

Tags: python

I am trying to enter the command "remove" followed by indexes so that specific strings on a "to-do" list can be removed, is there any way I can do this without confusing the compiler and mistaking integers for strings. (I get the TypeError: string indices must be integers error as half of the command is a string, while the other is a number)

p.s. - id assume to use the .split tag so that I can pass arguments, however, I already have a function that parses commands.

````
todo_list = []

def parse_command(cmd):
    arg = cmd.split()
    if arg[0] == 'add':
        add_item(arg[1])
    elif arg[0] == 'remove':
        remove_item(arg[1])
    elif arg[0] == 'move':
        move_item(arg[1], arg[2])
    elif arg[0] == 'list':
        list_items()
    else:
        print("not a valid command")
    
    
def add_item(item):
    for i in range(0, 1):
        tasks = item
        todo_list.append(tasks)
    print("Your to-do list so far: ", todo_list)
    
def remove_item(idx):
    for idx in todo_list:
        if cmd == idx[cmd]:
            todo_list.pop(int(cmd))
    
    
def move_item(idx1, idx2):
    return("This function moves! ")
    
def list_items():
    for x in range(len(todo_list)):
        return todo_list[x]
                
while(True):
    
    cmd = input("Please input command: ")
    parse_command(cmd) 


#input: Please input command: add hello
       #Your to-do list so far:  ['hello']
       #Please input command: add stack_overflow!
       #Your to-do list so far:  ['hello', 'stack_overflow!']
       #Please input command: remove 1

#after inputting "remove 1" it spits this message out:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-78-9b3707886f99> in <module>
     37 
     38     cmd = input("Please input command: ")
---> 39     parse_command(cmd)
     40 
     41 

<ipython-input-78-9b3707886f99> in parse_command(cmd)
      6         add_item(arg[1])
      7     elif arg[0] == 'remove':
----> 8         remove_item(arg[1])
      9     elif arg[0] == 'move':
     10         move_item(arg[1], arg[2])

<ipython-input-78-9b3707886f99> in remove_item(idx)
     23 def remove_item(idx):
     24     for idx in todo_list:
---> 25         if cmd == idx[cmd]:
     26             todo_list.pop(idx)
     27 

TypeError: string indices must be integers```
````

Comment: Welcome to SO, please see [mre] it would help if you could provide sample input and the expected output.

Comment: I don't understand your question's body, but judging from the title the answer is `list.pop(int(input()))`.

Comment: updated the post so that it involves all the code for better understanding, sorry!

Comment: The compiler is not confused and is not making a mistake. `input()` takes a string so if you want to use part of that string as a number you have to convert it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can delete item from list by the `idx` index value:

```
def remove_item(idx):
    print("idx {} cmd {}".format(idx, cmd)) # cmd = remove 1

    #remove by index
    todo_list.pop(int(idx))
```

The reason you get Type Error is because of following line:

`if cmd == idx[cmd]:` which is a bit unclear to me.

However, the above function works fine